# Changing background image in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am currently working on a weather app that changes background based on time of the day and the weather description. I created a state that handles the background style of the page.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      city: undefined,
      country: undefined,
      localtime: undefined,
      timezone: undefined,
      temperature: undefined,
      precip: undefined,
      humidity: undefined,
      weather_icon: undefined,
      weather_description: "",
      error: false,
      backgroundStyle: {
        backgroundImage: undefined,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
      }
    };
  }
```

I also created a function that handles the logic of the background change. In it also is an array holding the images for the background. For example,

```
const bgImage = [
      "",
      "'url(img/snowy.jpg)'",
      "'url(img/night.jpg)'",
      "'url(img/sunny.jpg)'",
      "'url(img/stormy.jpg)'",
      "'url(img/sunset.jpg)'",
      "'url(img/night-rain.jpg)'",
      "'url(img/snow-night.jpg)'"
    ]
    // Check for rain
    if (description === 'showers' || description.includes('rain')) {
      if (time >= 20 || (time >= 0 && time < 7)) {
        this.setState({
          backgroundStyle: {
            backgroundImage: bgImage[6]
          }
        });
      } else if (time > 7 && time < 20) {
        this.setState({
          backgroundStyle: {
            backgroundImage: bgImage[0]
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          backgroundStyle: {
            backgroundImage: bgImage[0]
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

In the render function, I return a div and with the style

```
<div className="App" style={this.state.backgroundStyle}>
```

The images do not load and I am not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you double wrapping them in strings? It works if your array was like this: `const bgImage = ["url(img/snowy.jpg)"...]` instead of this: `const bgImage = ["'url(img/snowy.jpg)'"...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd highly recommend you to store this kind of static files on a CDN, it will make your client lighter!

But, if you want to use a local image you have two choices.

**You can import the image file** and use it like any other imported object.

```
import snowy from '../../snowy.jpg';
import night from '../../night.jpg';
import sunny from '../../sunny.jpg';
import stormy from '../../stormy.jpg';
import sunset from '../../sunset.jpg';
import nightRain from '../../night-rain.jpg';
import snowNight from '../../snow-night.jpg';

const bgImage = [
      "",
      snowy,
      night,
      sunny,
      stormy,
      sunset,
      nightRain,
      snowNight,
]
```

or

**You need to provide the relative path to the folder**, for example: `../../img/snowy.jpg`, remember that the relative path refers to the current file in which the path is written.

**edit:**

You can also use something like:

```
const bgImg = `url(${this.state.backgroundStyle.backgroundImage})`
```

Comment: Ended up discarding the array and importing the images individually. Thanks

Comment: Nice, this can make the code clearer! Mostly, using arrays indexes is not safe, because it's not flexible, nor scalable..

Answer (score 1):

Once your url() is under "" Webpack won't be able to find the images later at runtime.

try using:

```
import logo from './logo.png'; // this will tell webpack that you are using this file, therefore it will be included like logo.<chunk>.png
```

Comment: This actually worked. Ended up discarding the array and importing the images individually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it would be because you are wrapping the strings in the `bgImage` array in single and double quotes at the same time